# List<object> compare

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have searched for a few examples and not found one that is similar to what I have and what I want to achieve.

I have 2 lists

```
class object1
{
   string obj1_name;
   int obj1_qty;
}
List<object1> listA

class object2
{
   string obj2_name;
   int obj2_qty;
}
List<object2> listB;
```

Now, using ListA as the primary list I want to see if ListB contains an object with the same name and if so, what is the quantity and hence, does the obj1_qty = obj2_qty each other? if not, there is a difference and I need to show it, most likely in a 3rd list which would be the difference, of the qty's if they exist. Note, ListA can be bigger or smaller than ListB

- Show All List A (master list contains all objects)
- Show the difference between those names/qty's that exist in both lists.

Gracias

Comment: I suggest you post what you have tried so far. Not many people are prepared to write code for you if you don't show you have made an effort.

Comment: Why do you need 2 classes which have the same `members`?

Comment: Is it possible that both objects could inherit from the same interface that expose `Name` and `Qty` properties? Also as-is your code is not complieable and may be closed. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18468317/edit) and at least give complete compilable versions of the classes.

Comment: HI Scott. I find too little code I get negative comments, too much code I get negative answers... But thanks for your approach.. The objects cannot inherit form the same interface because the classes are different. I have simplified it here. List A has 5 objects and List B has 3, I am only interested in those displayed above

Answer (score 3):

Souncs like a join would work for you:

```
var query = from a in listA
            join b in listB on a.obj1_name equals b.obj2_name
            where a.obj1_qty != b.obj2_qty
            select new {
                Name = a.obj1_name,
                QtyA = a.obj1_qty,
                QtyB = b.obj2_qty,
                Diff = a.obj1_qty - b.obj2_qty
                };
```

Comment: You need to replace the `=` in your `on` [with `equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain always forget that part - thanks, fixed.

Comment: @DStanley. are you missing a .ToList() ....  pardon my ignorance

Comment: You don't _need_ a `ToList()` unless you actually want a `List`.  You can still iterate the results without it.

Answer (score 2):

The simpelest way to do this is just use a join from Linq

```
var items = from l1 in listA
            join l2tmp1 in listB on l1.obj1_name equals l2.obj2_name into l2tmp2
            from l2 in l2tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty();
            select new { 
                 ItemA = l1, 
                 ItemB = l2, 
                 Name = l1.obj1_name, 
                 Difference = (l2 == null) ? 0 : l1.ob1_qty - l2.ob2_qty
            };
```

`items` will now hold a `IEnumerable` of a anonymous class that holds the a reference to the item in ListA, a reference to the item in listB, the matching name, and the difference.

Comment: So if he did use the interface what solution would you use?

Comment: A custom IEqualityComparer to compare the two then using... Ok, you are right, a interface would not help. I have removed that part from my answer.

Comment: An interface would likely be helpful for other problems when dealing with this data, but for *this particular problem* a Join is likely best/easiest, regardless of whether they implement the same interface or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: This works. However, if List A has 37 elements and List B has 34, the new var items has only 34 elements. The extra 3 elements which do not exist in List B but do exist in List A go missing

Comment: You said in your question "*I want to see if listB contains an object with the same name*" if there is no item in listB that matches then you said you did not care about the object. Please clarify by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18468317/edit) exactly what you want in your result set if a object does not exist in listA or listB.

Comment: @Timujin I have changed the code now to do a "left join" `ItemB` will be null where there are no matches and Difference will return `0`